# jQuery Chrome does not accept hidden for button

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I thought that recent Chrome and Firefox browsers do accept classic jQuery commands, but that's not true at all. I planned to temporary hide few buttons (some kind of CRUD) at the start of form with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#jQtab2" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [ 1, 2, 3 ] ); //at first
  $("#btnSave").css("visibility", "hidden"); 
  $("#btnCancel").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

and in Firefox it worked well, as expected, but stubborn Chrome refuse to obey. After press F5 to refresh, Chrome sometimes hides btnSave, sometimes not, but always both browsers hide btnCancel!? Why!?
Thanks.

Comment: I just tried it on Chrome and it works. I guess your problem is elsewhere. Please build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces the issue

Comment: Provide the code you have

Comment: Too big code. I thought how to put it on jsFiddle but in meantime I got acceptable solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the button, Please try to below methods.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnSave").css("display", "none"); 
  $("#btnCancel").css("display", "none");
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnSave").css("opacity", "0"); 
  $("#btnCancel").css("opacity", "0");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This second variant is enough good for my purpose because with: display: none is not possible to show up hidden control again. Butm by change of opacity it's easy to change from 0 to 100!